# Storing Multiple .NET Arrays (Matlab)

Tags: .net, arrays, matlab, matrix, type-conversion

How can I store .NET arrays in a matrix without converting them to another data type?

If I have

```
A = NET.createArray('System.Int16', n);
B = NET.createArray('System.Int16', n);
```

How to do I store these in the same matrix without first converting them to another data type such as `double` or `int16` etc

So I can access them by

```
data(1) outputs A
data(2) outputs B
```

*This is a more specific question relating to my original question:* [Preallocating a Matrix of .NET Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46035872/preallocating-a-matrix-of-net-arrays)

Comment: Storing a .NET array in a structure works, but I do not know how to extract the .NET array for later use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that storing the .NET array in a cell means you can later extract it and index as such

```
data{1} = NET.createArray('System.Int16', n);
data{2} = NET.createArray('System.Int16', n);
```

data{i} returns a .NET array which can be converted to another data type and plotted